# How to start accelerometer activity inside MainActivity

Tags: java, android

This is my `SensorActivity`  class, which is declared inside `MainActivity`. How can I start the `accelerometer` sensor in the `onCreate` method of the `MainActivity`?

```
public class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
    private final SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private final Sensor mAccelerometer;


    public SensorActivity() {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

       //DO THINGS

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new activity by intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.SensorActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```